# C Programming Struct

Tags: c, struct

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

struct s {
    char ch[20];
    float a;
};

int main()
{
    struct s p[10];
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        scanf("%s%f",p[i].ch,p[i].a);
    }
}
```

What is wrong with this code?

Its giving runtime error.

What's the problem?

Answer (score 7):

Most of the errors come from this line.

```
scanf("%s%f",p[i].ch,p[i].a);
```

You should use the address of `p[i].a`, and also restrict the numbers of chars to write in `p[i].ch`.

```
scanf( "%19s%f", p[i].ch, &p[i].a );
```

Comment: Correct reasoning with the upper limit with %nums. +1. It is worth mentioning that even if you try to enter more characters, the %19s will simply ignore the additional ones.

Comment: You should also mention that the code should be `if (scanf("%19s%f", p[i].ch, &p[i].a) != 2) { ...read error... }`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler From `man scanf`: "s" Matches a sequence of non-white-space characters; the next pointer must be a pointer to character array that is long enough to hold the  input sequence and the terminating null byte ('\0'), which is added automatically.

Comment: What @JonathanLeffler meant was to add check for the number of inputs taken by scanf i.e. the return value which is 2 since it takes input in two fields total.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler @fayyazkl I was rather trying to interpret the help of `scanf` to check whether it is actually `19` or `20` to be used. I wrote 19 at first shot, then corrected to 20 after reading the excerpt of `man scanf`, then was corrected to 19 again ... I wrote a sample program. Definitely, it's 19.

Answer (score 3):

I haven't touched C code for a while but shouldn't it be something like

```
scanf("%s%f",p[i].ch,&(p[i].a));
```

(You have to give the memory address of the variables to the `scanf` function.)

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is in the `p[i].a` parameter;
use `&p[i].a` instead.

Comment: @LiranElisha why alloc? It is already allocated fine. At least for me, that is why you didn't get the upvote

Comment: It WAS there in the answer above BEFORE the silent edit :) The fundamental flaw of not using address op was fine though. Also the other answer elaborated with %<num>s restricting the input length. Hence i believe it deserves the higher upvotes :).

Answer (score 2):

At the line:

```
scanf("%s%f", p[i].ch, p[i].a);
```

You are using `p[i].a` as a `float*` (pointer), while it's a `float`. You're invoking undefined behavior. You probably wanted to do it like this:

```
scanf("%s%f", p[i].ch, &p[i].a);
```

Answer (score 2):

Change your code like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
struct s {
    char ch[20];
    float a;
};

int main(){
    struct s p[10];
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<10;i++){
        scanf("%s%f",p[i].ch, &p[i].a);
    }
}
```

Note that variable `a` is a `float` type; you need to pass its memory address when using `scanf`.